# Not able to process request after multiple thread creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, threadpool

Created a static ExecutorService object and used it to execute an async task with input in a spring boot rest controller. not able to process any request after invoking async task for 3 times.

**TaskManager.java**

```
public class TaskManager {
    static ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    private TaskManager(){

    }
    public static void addAsyncTask(AsyncTaskWrapper task){
        e.submit(task);
    }
}
```

```
 public class AsyncTaskWrapper implements Callable {
    Object input,output;
    Callable callback;
    AsyncTask task;
    public Object getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(Object input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public Object getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public AsyncTask getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(AsyncTask task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public Callable getCallback() {
        return callback;
    }

    public void setCallback(Callable callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public AsyncTaskWrapper(AsyncTask task, Callable callback){
        this.callback = callback;
        this.task = task;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Started");
        output = task.execute(input);
        callback.call();
        System.out.println("call completed");
        return output;
    }
}
```

**RESTControllers.java** - need to execute a task in async with input for a RESTEndpoint.

```
AsyncTaskWrapper task = new AsyncTaskWrapper(
    (list) -> {
        List l = (List) list;
        try {
                MailingUtils.sendRegistrationMail((String) l.get(0), (String) l.get(1));
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    },
    () -> {
        System.out.println("Done");
        return null;
    });

task.setInput(objects);
TaskManager.addAsyncTask(task);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does *System.out.println("call completed");* ever get printed?

Comment: If all threads are active then requests will be queued

Comment: Yes for 2 request the south call completed shows up. @scarywombat

Comment: @deadpool but the request should process at some point of time right but in this case it is behaving like dead lock.

Comment: Seems to be problem with AsyncTaskWrapper. Need full code.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar it just has getters and setters